# Tail of hitting times for Brownian motion on the circle

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

For $y\in \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ and $\varphi\in C([0,\infty);\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)$ 
let

$T_{y}(\varphi) \  := \   \inf\{t>0: \varphi_t = y \} \ \ \ $      (first time the path $\varphi$ hits $y$)

and, for each $x\in \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$, let
 $\mathbb P_x$ be the Wiener measure on
$ C([0,\infty);\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)$  with starting point $x$.

I want to show that there exist constants $\alpha,\beta>0$ such that for every 
$t>0$ and $x,y\in \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$

$ \mathbb P_x (T_y \geq t)   \         \leq   \  \alpha e^{-\beta t}    \ \ \ \ \  (*) $

I think one way to show it would be:
to show first that there exist 
$K,K'>0$ such that

$      \inf_{x,y\in \mathbb R/\mathbb Z}   \mathbb P_{x} (T_y \leq K) \geq K'  $

and then iterate the Markov property to get (*).

Any suggestion?